# How to get Json as key and value in the Ajax $.getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, getjson

I have this ajax code for getting json from Jobs.json file.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn2').click( callJobs );
        });

function callJobs()
{


     alert("getting results...");
    $.getJSON('Jobs.json', function(JSON){
        $('#result').empty();

        $.each(JSON.jobs, function(i, JOB){
            $('#result')
            .append(JOB.Job +'<br />')
            .append(JOB.Priority+'<br />')
            .append(JOB.DueDate+'<br />')
            .append(JOB.Iscompleted+'<hr />');
      });
    });
}
```

Jobs.json code is below.

```
{
"jobs":[
  {
     "Job":"Job1",
     "Priority":"Low",
     "DueDate":"11.03.2013",
     "Iscompleted":"No"
  },
  {
     "Job":"Job2",
     "Priority":"High",
     "DueDate":"11.03.2013",
     "Iscompleted" : "No"
  },
  {
     "Job":"Job3",
     "Priority":"Medium",
     "DueDate":"11.03.2013",
     "Iscompleted":"No"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Now I want to rewrite $.each function dynamically.That is, it will write the json string as key and value instead of .append() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would walk over the properties of each job dynamically:

```
$.getJSON('Jobs.json', function(JSON){
    var $container = $('#result').empty();

    $.each(JSON.jobs, function(i, JOB) {
        $.each(JOB, function(key, value) {
            $container.append(key + ': ' + value + '<br />');
        });
        $container.append('<hr />');
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/isizos/1/)

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.I wonder that why it is not working.It looks right.

Comment: function callJobs()
 {
   alert("getting results...");    var $container = $('#result');

$.each(JSON.jobs, function(i, JOB) {
    $.each(JOB, function(key, value) {
        $container.append(key + ': ' + value + '<br />');
    });
    $container.append('<hr />');   });
} I wrote like this.Which one is wrong?

Comment: I saw that it works.However I cannot run it my project.Thank you.

Comment: @ntf I've made an edit in my answer to show you how it would work inside your code.

Comment: @ntf Great! Btw, I wouldn't choose `JSON` for my variable names, because it shadows `window.JSON` which on most browsers enables the json handling methods.

Comment: @ntf Also, since you're new, read [about] to see how you accept answers.

Comment: @Jack: This appends an extra `<br />` after the last property and before the `<hr />`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach. I've added comments to explain the process.

```
$.each(JSON.jobs, function(i, JOB) {
    // an empty array for the output values
    var values = [];
    // iterator over each property in the current JOB object
    for (var prop in JOB) { 
        // add an item to the array in format "key: value"
        values.push(prop + ': ' + JOB[prop]); 
    }
    // join the array values using '<br />' as separator; 
    // append to #result and add an '<hr />' after
    $('#result').append(values.join('<br />')).append('<hr />');
});
```

My goals for this solution were to keep it readable (at the cost of an added array), select the `#result` element only once, and not have to deal with knowing whether to add that last `<br />` during each loop. The other solutions append an extra `<br />` after the last property and before the `<hr />` whereas this and your original solution do not.

Comment: I added this code to my file and it works.Thank you very much.I have one question also.When more parameters are added into Json file ,will it work?Will Key and values are passed?

Comment: @ntf: Yes, as more parameters are added it should just work! Also, I see you're new here. You should upvote/accept answers that were helpful or worked for you.

Comment: I like this, its a very clean solution.  +1

Comment: @Cory 15 reputation is needed to upvote/accept.I am sorry I cannot give vote for now.

Comment: @ntf You shouldn't need any reputation to accept an answer to your own question.